# Matplotlib way to annotate bar plots with lines and figures

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[image]

I would like to create an annotation to a bar chart that compares the value of the bar to two reference values. An overlay such as shown in the picture, a kind of staff gauge, is possible, but I'm open to more elegant solutions.

The bar chart is generated with the `pandas` API to `matplotlib` (e.g. `data.plot(kind="bar")`), so a plus would be if the solution is playing nicely with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use smaller bars for the target and benchmark indicators. Pandas cannot annotate bars automatically, but you can simply loop over the values and use matplotlib's `pyplot.annotate` instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.randint(5,15, size=5)
t = (a+np.random.normal(size=len(a))*2).round(2)
b = (a+np.random.normal(size=len(a))*2).round(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":a, "t":t, "b":b})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


df["a"].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, legend=True)
df["b"].plot(kind='bar', position=0., width=0.1, color="lightblue",legend=True, ax=ax)
df["t"].plot(kind='bar', position=1., width=0.1, color="purple", legend=True, ax=ax)

for i, rows in df.iterrows():
    plt.annotate(rows["a"], xy=(i, rows["a"]), rotation=0, color="C0")
    plt.annotate(rows["b"], xy=(i+0.1, rows["b"]), color="lightblue", rotation=+20, ha="left")
    plt.annotate(rows["t"], xy=(i-0.1, rows["t"]), color="purple", rotation=-20, ha="right")

ax.set_xlim(-1,len(df))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to annotate a bar plot (as far as I am aware) Some time ago I needed to annotate one so I wrote this, perhaps you can adapt it to your needs.
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(-0.2, 3.2)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle=':', lw=.5, zorder=1)
# x,y data
x = np.arange(4)
y = np.array([5, 12, 3, 7])
# Define upper y limit leaving space for the text above the bars.
up = max(y) * .03
ax.set_ylim(0, max(y) + 3 * up)
ax.bar(x, y, align='center', width=0.2, color='g', zorder=4)
# Add text to bars
for xi, yi, l in zip(*[x, y, list(map(str, y))]):
    ax.text(xi - len(l) * .02, yi + up, l,
            bbox=dict(facecolor='w', edgecolor='w', alpha=.5))
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=12)
plt.show()
```